# Який зв'язок вигуки "гайта" і "вісьта" мають зі словами "направо" і "наліво""?

Tags: етимологія

У пісні [Бо війна війною](https://nashe.com.ua/song/16380) натрапила на такі рядки:

> Бо війна війною, **вісьта-вйо**,
>
> В тім є Божа сила, **гайта-вйо**!

Ці вигуки використовують при управлінні кіньми. [Вісьта означає - на ліво, гайта - на право](https://almukantar.livejournal.com/7849.html).

Цікавить, яким чином ці вигуки набули саме таких значеь. В [Етимологічному словнику](http://litopys.org.ua/djvu/etymolog_slovnyk.htm) **вісьта** немає, а **гайта** (відсилання до словникової статті **гаття**) не пояснює появи значення **направо**.
Отже, який зв'язок вигуки "гайта" і "вісьта" мають зі словами "направо" і "наліво""?

Answer (score 6):

Насправді згаданий вами етимолоґічнай словник все-таки має *вісьта*, але для цього треба дивити:

> [**віста**](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=405) «ліворуч» — вигук при завертанні коней.
>
> Похоџення неясне, могло виникнути з специфічного свисту, яким поганяють коней.
>
> Фонетічні та словотвірні варіянти: *вістя*, *вісшта*, ***вісьта***, *вішта*, *віштя* «тс.», *віштя*, *віштяк* (прізвисько подільського селянина за те, що, повертаючи коней ліворуч, він вигукує віштя).

Про всяк приперепишу *за вас* словопохоџення *гайта*:

> [**гаття**](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom1.pdf#page=481) — вигук, яким підганяють коней; вигук, яким завертають коней направо (Л, Mel)
>
> польська hajta, hajt, hejt, hejta, hejtta, heta, hettia, старопольська hecia (з украӥньської?);
>
> українські форми можуть бути пояснені як результат фонетичної видозміни виразу *од тя* (*от тя*) «від тебе», який спочатку адресувався поводиреві коней під час оранки;
>
> придихове **г** виникло у зв’язку з вигуковим характером слова (можливо, також під впливом вигуків *гей*, *гайда*, *гайт*)
>
> питання про походження німецького hott «гаття», hotta, hotte «тс.», від яких виводиться також чеська hot, словацька hota, вл. hót, hóte, нл. hot «тс.» (Sławski I 419–420) залишається відкритим (Kluge–Götze 330)
>
> Див. ще **від**, **ти**
>
> Фонетічні й словотвірні варіянти: *атя*, ***гайта***, *гать*, *гатьта*, *гатя*, *гейта*, *гетта*, *геття*, *гиття*, *гитя*, *готьта* «тс.»

Тобто ці вигуки, котрі не не обов’язково мусять вказувати на якийсь бік, знайшли власного пристосування, як спонуки для і до коней, а з часом поширило ся всюди, хоча однаково можливі розбіжності, котрих вказує і [словник Стуса](http://slovopedia.org.ua/27/53395/166.html):

> **гайта-вйо**, **вішта-вйо**, *діал.* Вигуки, які у різних діалектах України мають відмінне значення: в одних спонука візника до коней „вперед“; в інших — також спонука до підганяння зі значенням „вправо-вліво“.

Answer (score -1):

Мій дідусь завжди використовував ці слова для вказівок якщо ми удвох щось переносили, а на селі так управляли кіньми.

Вісьта - вліво, гайта - вправо.

Але я думаю, що подібно до "віра"-"майна", це можуть бути запозичені/адаптовані слова, наприклад норвезькою вліво звучить як "венстре" (venstre) а вправо "гойре" (høyre).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).